# Cosine fourier series integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If I have even piecewise periodic function ($T=6$)
$$x(t)=\begin{cases} 0 &-3\leq t \leq-2  \\ 2+t &-2\leq t \leq-1 \\ 1 &-1\leq t \leq 1 \\ -t+2      &1\leq t \leq 2 \\ 0 &1 \leq t \leq 2\end{cases}$$

Find cosine fourier series for this function. So I need to calculate the fourier coefficient $a_0$ and $a_n$ because $b_n=0$ for even function.

$a_0$ is easy
$$ a_0=\frac 1T \int_T x(t)dt = \frac 12$$

$a_n$ I did all by hand with integration by parts but I skip some steps now

\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac 2 T\int_T x(t)\cos(n2\pi t/T) dt \\
&=\frac 13\left(\int_{-2}^{-1} (2+t)\cos(n\pi t/3)dt+\int_{-1}^1\cos(n \pi t/3)dt + \int_1^2 (2-t) \cos (n \pi t/3)dt \right) \\ 
&=\int_{-1}^1 \cos(n \pi /3)dt = \frac{6 \sin(n \pi t /3)}{n\pi}
\end{align}

Well what I found is that the first and second integral cancel each other out. I guess this is trivial knowledge to most when you see the integrals but not to me. Is there a way to see easily that $\int_{-2}^{-1} (2+t)\cos(n\pi t/3)dt=-\int_1^2 (2-t) \cos (n \pi t/3)dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable substitution. If you define $T= -t$, and substitute the variable in the second equation it does the trick.

$dt$ becomes $-dT$, $-t$ becomes $+T$, $\cos(T)=\cos(-T) $ and the integration limits becomes -2 and -1. If you exchange them you can change the sign, and you have your equality

Comment: Of course. Thank you!